# Attaching a EBS Volume to EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, mount

I followed the steps as described on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-add-volume-to-instance.html

It worked well until the last point. I get the following error

```
root@ip-10-134-145-102:/home/ubuntu/crsq# mount -a
mount: special device /dev/xvdb does not exist
```

My file system is as follows:

```
root@ip-10-134-145-102:/home/ubuntu/crsq# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  4.2G  3.4G  56% /
udev            819M   12K  819M   1% /dev
tmpfs           331M  184K  331M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            827M     0  827M   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdf        99G  188M   94G   1% /mnt/dbmount
```

The final fstab file is as follows:

```
root@ip-10-134-145-102:/home/ubuntu/crsq# cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
/dev/xvdb   /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
/dev/xvda3  none    swap    sw,comment=cloudconfig  0   0
/dev/xvdf       /mnt/dbmount   ext4    defaults        0       2
```

The original fstab file is as:

```
root@ip-10-134-145-102:/home/ubuntu/crsq# cat /etc/fstab.orig 
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults    0 0
/dev/xvdb   /mnt    auto    defaults,nobootwait,comment=cloudconfig 0   2
/dev/xvda3  none    swap    sw,comment=cloudconfig  0   0
```

Comment: Much simpler solution. Extend the volume. I posted my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78188244/156522

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message is just saying that `/dev/xvdb` more than likely you are using an fstab from an instance that had an ephemeral storage as `/dev/xvdb`. Regardless, that message should not affect the mounting of `/dev/xvdf` which is the EBS Volume that you want to mount. -- You can even see it when you run `df -h`.

To remove the `/dev/xvdb` message you can just remove the line containing `/dev/xvdb` from your fstab file.

Comment: the aws tutorial says that "Errors in the /etc/fstab file can render a system unbootable. Do not shut down a system that has errors in the /etc/fstab file." . This is an error right? and I do not think mounting was done by sudo mount -a . I had already mount the volume before changing the fstab file. This is just to ensure that whenever I reboot, the instance is still attached.

Comment: That's correct but not all errors render it unbootable. Try commenting the line one and then run `sudo mount -a` and see if you don't get any errors. If you don't then you are safe to reboot