# Attaching and mounting existing EBS volume to EC2 instance filesystem issue

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I had some unknown issue with my old EC2 instance so that I can't ssh into it anymore. Therefore I'm attempting to create a new EBS volume from a snapshot of the old volume and mount it into the new instance. Here is exactly what I did:

1. Created a new volume from snapshot of the old one.
2. Created a new EC2 instance and attached the volume to it as `/dev/xvdf` (or `/dev/sdf`)
3. SSHed into the instance and attempted to mount the old volume with:

`$ sudo mkdir -m 000 /vol $ sudo mount /dev/xvdf /vol`

And the output was:

```
mount: block device /dev/xvdf is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

I know I should specify the filesytem as `ext4` but the volume contains a lot of important data, so I cannot afford to format it with `$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf`. If I try `sudo mount /dev/xvdf /vol -t ext4` (no formatting) I get:

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

And `dmesg | tail` gives me:

```
[ 1433.217915] EXT4-fs (xvdf): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1433.222107] FAT-fs (xvdf): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 1433.226127] FAT-fs (xvdf): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 1433.260752] EXT4-fs (xvdf): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1433.265563] EXT4-fs (xvdf): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1433.270477] EXT4-fs (xvdf): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[ 1433.274549] FAT-fs (xvdf): bogus number of reserved sectors
[ 1433.277632] FAT-fs (xvdf): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[ 1433.306549] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
[ 2373.694570] EXT4-fs (xvdf): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
```

By the way, the 'mounting read-only' message also worries me but I haven't look into it yet since I can't mount the volume at all.

Comment: I updated my answer. Does that work for you?

Comment: A simpler solution is to extend your volume. Posted answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78188244/156522

Answer (score 121, accepted):

## The One Liner

---

Mount the partition *(if disk is partitioned)*:

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /vol -t ext4
```

Mount the disk *(if not partitioned)*:

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf /vol -t ext4
```

where:

- `/dev/xvdf` is changed to the EBS Volume **device** being mounted
- `/vol` is changed to the **folder** you want to mount to.
- `ext4` is the **filesystem type** of the volume being mounted

---

## Common Mistakes How To:

---

### ✳️ Attached Devices List

Check your mount command for the **correct** EBS Volume **device name** and **filesystem type**. The following will list them all:

```
sudo lsblk --output NAME,TYPE,SIZE,FSTYPE,MOUNTPOINT,UUID,LABEL
```

**If your EBS Volume displays with an attached `partition`, mount the `partition`; not the disk.**

---

### ✳️ If your volume isn't listed

If it doesn't show, you didn't `Attach` your EBS Volume in AWS web-console

---

### ✳️ Auto Remounting on Reboot

These devices become unmounted again if the EC2 Instance ever reboots.

A way to make them mount again upon startup is to add the volume to the server's `/etc/fstab` file.

**Caution:**
If you corrupt the `/etc/fstab` file, it will make your system unbootable. Read AWS's short article so you know to check that you did it correctly.

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html#ebs-mount-after-reboot

**First**:
With the `lsblk` command above, find your volume's `UUID` & `FSTYPE`.

**Second**:
Keep a copy of your original `fstab` file.

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.original
```

**Third**:
Add a line for the volume in `sudo nano /etc/fstab`.

The fields of `fstab` are 'tab-separated' and each line has the following fields:

```
<UUID>  <MOUNTPOINT>    <FSTYPE>    defaults,discard,nofail 0   0
```

Here's an example to help you, my own `fstab` reads as follows:

```
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /   ext4    defaults,discard,nofail 0   0
UUID=e4a4b1df-cf4a-469b-af45-89beceea5df7   /var/www-data   ext4    defaults,discard,nofail 0   0
```

---

That's it, you're done. Check for errors in your work by running:

```
sudo mount --all --verbose
```

You will see something like this if things are :

```
/                   : ignored
/var/www-data       : already mounted
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. I'll edit the question do you may see the outputs.

Comment: The mount command I gave in my answer does not overwrite your Volume filesystem so you don't need to be worried about losing data.  Also, rest assured that if things go wrong.. you can just re-create a new copy of your Volume from the original EBS snapshot like you did to create the volume in the first place.  Do my mount command, it is non-destructive. I promise.  And if you do recreate a new volume, make sure it is not a read-only replica.

Comment: I had already tried that, just forgot to put it in the question. Thanks for the tip on the 'read-only' problem.

Comment: I read your update.  Use this to check the filesystem type and update the mount command with what it tells you for TYPE=""     Use: blkid /dev/xvdf

Comment: Solved it! Thank you very much for the help. After getting no output at all from the command you mentioned, I noticed that for some reason the volume was located at `/dev/xvdf1`, not `/dev/xvdf`. Simple mistake, sorry. `Using sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /vol -t ext4` worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for reporting back!  Super happy you got this figured out. Rock on.

Comment: @GabrielRebello Thanks for your comment, that saved me. I'll make it an answer, just to give it more visability

Comment: You should be mounting drives in /etc/fstab not by running a mount command in the rc.local

Comment: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

Answer (score 26):

I encountered this problem too after adding a new 16GB volume and attaching it to an existing instance. First of all you need to know what disks you have present
Run

```
  sudo fdisk -l
```

You'll' have an output that appears like the one shown below detailing information about your disks (volumes"

```
 Disk /dev/xvda: 12.9 GB, 12884901888 bytes
  255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1566 cylinders, total 25165824 sectors
  Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
  Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
  Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1   *       16065    25157789    12570862+  83  Linux

 Disk /dev/xvdf: 17.2 GB, 17179869184 bytes
 255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2088 cylinders, total 33554432 sectors
 Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
 Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
 Disk identifier: 0x00000000

 Disk /dev/xvdf doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

As you can see the newly added Disk /dev/xvdf is present. To make it available you need to create a filesystem on it and mount it to a mount point. You can achieve that with the following commands

```
 sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf
```

**Making a new file system clears everything in the volume so do this on a fresh volume without important data**

Then mount it maybe in a directory under the /mnt folder

```
 sudo mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/dir/
```

Confirm that you have mounted the volume to the instance by running

```
  df -h
```

This is what you should have

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
 udev            486M   12K  486M   1% /dev
 tmpfs           100M  400K   99M   1% /run
 /dev/xvda1       12G  5.5G  5.7G  50% /
 none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
 none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
 none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
 none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
 /dev/xvdf        16G   44M   15G   1% /mnt/ebs
```

And that's it you have the volume for use there attached to your existing instance.
[credit](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/07/31/aws-attaching-an-ebs-volume-on-an-ec2-instance-and-making-it-available-for-use/)

Answer (score 25):

I noticed that for some reason the volume was located at `/dev/xvdf1`, not `/dev/xvdf`.

Using

```
sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /vol -t ext4
```

worked like a charm

Comment: xvdf is the disk, xvdf1 is the partition. If the disk is already partitioned like this, need to mount the partition itself.

Answer (score 13):

I encountered this problem, and I got it now,

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-63-130 ~]$ lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdf    202:80   0   8G  0 disk
└─xvdf1 202:81   0   8G  0 part
```

You should mount the `partition`

> /dev/xvdf1 (which type is a partition)

not mount the `disk`

> /dev/xvdf (which type is a disk)

Comment: This solved my problem. That was such a simple sense! Thanks!

Comment: So easy... Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me, but how is that, the accepted answer and all other sources mention mounting the xvdf instead of xvdf1?

Answer (score 6):

For me it was duplicate UUID error while mounting the volume, so I used "-o nouuid" option.

for e.g. mount -o nouuid /dev/xvdf1 /mnt

I found the clue from system logs, on CentOs, /var/log/messages and found the error:
kernel: XFS (xvdf1): Filesystem has duplicate UUID f41e390f-835b-4223-a9bb-9b45984ddf8d - can't mount

Answer (score 5):

I had different issue, here when I checked in dmesg logs, the issue was with same UUID of existing root volume and UUID of root volume of another ec2. So to fix this I mounted it on another Linux type of ec2. It worked.

Comment: +1 I was following the steps here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html#replacing-lost-key-pair and it instructs you to use the same AMI and instance type but that seems to result in the same Disk Identifier. Switching to a different AMI fixed it for me too. sudo fdisk -l will display the disk id

Comment: This happened to me as well. When I created another instance using the image of the instance of which I had lost the key, it created the volume with same UUID. So I created a new instance without using any image and then it mounted correctly

Answer (score 2):

First run below command

**lsblk /dev/xvdf**

Output will be something like below

**NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT**

**xvdf    202:80   0  10G  0 disk**

**├─xvdf1 202:81   0   1M  0 part**

**└─xvdf2 202:82   0  10G  0 part**

Then, check the size and then mount it that one.
In above cases, mount it like below

**mount /dev/xvdf2 /foldername**

Answer (score 1):

First check file system type with **"lsblk -f"** command,  in my case it is **"XFS"**

```
#lsblk -f
NAME    FSTYPE FSVER LABEL UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
xvda
├─xvda1
├─xvda2 vfat   FAT16 EFI   31C3-C85B                              17.1M    14% /boot/efi
└─xvda3 xfs          ROOT  6f6ccaeb-068f-4eb7-9228-afeb8e4d25df    7.6G    24% /
xvdf
├─xvdf1
├─xvdf2 vfat   FAT16 EFI   31C3-C85B
└─xvdf3 xfs          ROOT  6f6ccaeb-068f-4eb7-9228-afeb8e4d25df    5.4G    46% /mnt/da
```

modify your command according to the file system type.

```
mount -t xfs -o nouuid /dev/xvdf3 /mnt/data/
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create a file system of the newly created volume from the snapshot.simply attach the volume and mount the volume to the folder where you want. I have attached the new volume  to the same location of the previously deleted volume and it was working fine.

```
[ec2-user@ip-x-x-x-x vol1]$ sudo lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
xvda    202:0    0   8G  0 disk 
└─xvda1 202:1    0   8G  0 part /
xvdb    202:16   0  10G  0 disk /home/ec2-user/vol1
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually persist by pre-defining the UUID at the time of creating ext4 FS,I add a script on user data and launch the instance, works just fine without any issues:

Ex script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Create the directory to be mounted
sudo mkdir -p /data
# Create file system with pre-defined & Label (edit the device name as needed)
sudo mkfs -U aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa -L DATA -t ext4 /dev/nvme1n1 

# Mount
sudo mount /dev/nvme1n1 /data -t ext4

# Update the fstab to persist after reboot
sudo su -c "echo 'UUID=aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa   /data  ext4    defaults,discard,nofail 0   0' >> /etc/fstab"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me there was some mysterious file causing this issue.

For me I had to clear the directory using the following command.

```
sudo mkfs -t ext3 /dev/sdf
```

**Warning**: this might delete files you have saved.  So you can run `ls` to make sure you don't lose important saved files

Answer (score 0):

Some very good and helpful answers here but if you want to find the simplest solution, extend the volume of existing instance as it is supported in all new Ec2 instances
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-ebs-update-new-elastic-volumes-change-everything/

The doc says that after you increase the volume you will still have to expand it
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ebs/latest/userguide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html

I had to reboot my machine and I could see the additional 30GB I added

[image]