# No space left on device on AWS ubuntu after migration to larger instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I recently migrated an AWS instance of mine from a t2.micro with an 8GB hard drive to an instance with a 100GB hard drive, as the t2.micro had no space left on it.

Once I'd completed the migration I attempted to install jupyter, but received an IO error indicating the device is out of space.

```
sudo -H pip install jupyter
```

[image: screenshot of system info & error message]

I've read a few similar posts and relevant articles and have inspected the free disk space with `df -i`, yet it seems there is ample space left on every disk.

[image: screenshot of df -i output]

My understanding of linux devices and disks is far from complete, and I'm unsure of the source of the error and the solution to the problem.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks!

---

**Update**:

Here is the output of `df` and `df -h`, which shows the overflow filesystem as being 100% used.

[image: screenshot of df and df -h output]

And the output of `lsblk`.

[image: screenshot of lsblk output]

Is the problem the overflow filesystem being at 100%? And is the solution to resize partition and filesystems? Unsure as to how to do that.

Comment: Ask it on Server Fault. Also, I think you shouldn't use `df -i`, buf `df` or `df -h`

Comment: How exactly did you migrate? `df -i` shows free inodes in the filesystem. Run `df -h` to see free space and `lsblk` to show block devices with raw space. You probably expanded you block device (created larger volume from a snapshot), but didn't resize partition and filesystem.

Comment: So , here is the thing, when you say migrated i understand that you actually attached a volume to the instance and then mounted it on your linux cloud machine , right @GeeBrownit

Comment: Thanks all for the responses.

I've updated the post to include outputs from your suggested commands.

@NishantSingh I think you're right. I haven't yet completed the migration as I should have.

Comment: `sudo umount overflow` should fix it

Comment: Thank you @DusanBajic that made all the problems go away!

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the volume and mount the same onto the filesystem to recognize it,

[Attaching and mounting existing EBS volume to EC2 instance filesystem issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792272/attaching-and-mounting-existing-ebs-volume-to-ec2-instance-filesystem-issue)

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html

Answer (score 0):

`sudo umount overflow` should fix it
                    – Dusan Bajic