# No longer able to access AWS via SSH after moving SSL crt files

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, ssh

While Installing SSL Certificate on AWS, I renamed the old crt files (like a fool), and now I'm no longer able to access the AWS instance via SSH to fix the file names.

Is there a way to access my AWS instance's files other than SSH? Or, is there a way to continue using SSH to access the instance when the SSL certificates are down?

Originally when I was connecting after the change of file names, I got this prompt response from the server when SSH:

```
> ssh -vv -i tc.pem ubuntu@tc.com
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "tc.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to tc.com [1.1.1.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file tc.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file tc.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to tc.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by 1.1.1.1 port 22
```

At one point I did a reboot on the server and now, I'm getting this when I try to SSH in:

```
> ssh -i tc.pem ubuntu@tc.com
ssh: connect to host tc.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

If I could get into the server or access the files in any way to rename them, it would be an easy fix. Appreciate any help anybody can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do. Basically you will mount your EC2 instance's root volume (EBS volume) on another instancce, edit .ssh/authorized_keys and then reattach the volume back to your instance.

Here is an article that covers this step-by-step:

[SSH Key Access Recovery on EC2 Instances](http://blog.endpoint.com/2016/10/ssh-key-access-recovery-on-ec2-instances.html)

There are a number of similar articles on the Internet.

Comment: That worked just perfectly. I was in the middle of following [this other page](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/how-to-recover-an-unreachable-linux-instance/) that has pretty much the same information as the one you provided. I did have to mount it a little differently because it's an ext4, but that is also covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792272/attaching-and-mounting-existing-ebs-volume-to-ec2-instance-filesystem-issue). Thanks for your help, John!