# Issues with mounting new volume and creating files in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm having trouble mounting a newly created volume (general purpose SSD - gp2) of 100GB in an EC2 instance. I attach a newly created volume to an AWS instance through the AWS console. Now i search for the volume in the command line using

`lsblk`

which returns the following information

`xvdf    202:80   0  100G  0 disk`

Now when I try to mount the volume onto a directory

`sudo mount /dev/xvdf /data`

I get the following error

`mount: /data: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/xvdf, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

Using the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30777107/1652217), when I do

`sudo mount /dev/xvdf1 /data -t ext4`

However, I'm able to mount but when I try to create a folder `mkdir temp`, I get the following error

`mkdir: cannot create directory ‘temp1’: Permission denied`

Answer (score 3):

The inability to create files and folders are related to bad permissions. Doing the two following steps worked for me.

1. Creating a linux file system with `mkfs` preferably `ext4`. However this can result in data loss, so please backup data before trying this on a volume with existing data.

   `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf`
2. In order to solve the permissions problem change ownership of the mounted location (`/data`) to the login username that is used to ssh into the machine. This is typically `ubuntu` for most linux machines in EC2. Execute the following command after mount.

   `sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /data`

This solves the mount and permission issues and I'm able to mount, unmount and create files multiple times across different machines within the same sub-region.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a step to create file system, it should work like this - run as root user.

```
mkfs.ext4  /dev/xvdf
mount /dev/xvdf /data
echo '/dev/xvdf /data ext4    defaults        0 0' >> /etc/fstab
```

You don't need to set any permission on /data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer **The reason you are getting error is due to** `ownership of directories`.and creation of the filesystem on newly created volume.How i solve this was

1. lsblk    `to view available disk spaces and their mount poins`
2. sudo file -s /dev/xvdf  `file -s command to get information about a device, such as its file system type.` `data tells there is no fs`
3. sudo mkfs -t xfs /dev/xvdf  `this is imp to create filesystem on available volume`
4. sudo mkdir /data `# to create mount point`
5. sudo mount /dev/xvdf /data  `to mount your volume`

*Review the file permissions of your new volume mount to make sure that your users and applications can write to the volume*

*The mount point is not automatically preserved after rebooting your instance. To automatically mount this EBS volume after reboot, you need to fstab configuration file

Refer for further clarity [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html)